# Appending recommendation list to input field dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a drop down recommendation list to a input field dynamically . So if someone click on input field a drop down should be there , and when someone select any option the input field value should be updated.

i am trying using this code where this editabletext is the id of the input box.

```js
   $('#demo').on('click', '#editabletext', function (e)
            {

            var det = '<select id=\'dropdownlist\'><option value=\'1\'>1</option><option value=\'4\'>4</option><option value=\'5\'>5</option></select>';
                 $(e.target).append(det);
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="demo">
  <input id="editabletext" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create `jsfiddle`, so that, it is easy to understand.

Comment: Have you looked into jquery.ui, and there the "autocomplete" function? https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: If they are able to type anything but should have a list of existing options, why not use a [combobox](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox)?  If they can't do anything but select a value that exists, why are you using a textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple solution on you problem, so try it out:

```js
$('#editabletext').click(function(e) {
  $("#NavDropdownListContainer").css('visibility', 'visible')
});

$('.ms-qSuggest-listItem').click(function() {
  $('#editabletext').val($(this).text())
  $("#NavDropdownListContainer").css('visibility', 'hidden')
})
```

```css
.ms-qSuggest-listItem {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="editabletext" type=text>


<div id="NavDropdownListContainer" style="display: block; visibility: hidden; position: absolute;">
  <div style="width: 249px;">
    <div class="ms-qSuggest-listItem">Everything</div>
    <div class="ms-qSuggest-listItem">People</div>
    <div class="ms-qSuggest-listItem">Conversations</div>
    <div class="ms-qSuggest-listItem">This Site</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is replacing the whole input field ..i want this appended to the input box itself.. something like autocomplete of jquery ui. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: @HimanshuKhandelwal I have edited the code, and I now think this is a god start on your solution. Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

JQuery UI already does this with [autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), its also free.

Try typing **PHP** or **Lisp** into the textbox in the snippet below

```js
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/5wnofhjc/

```js
$(document).on('click', 'input#editabletext', function (e){
  var det = `<ul id='dropdownlist'>
                <li value='1'>1</li>
                <li value='4'>4</li>
                <li value='5'>5</li>
            </ul>`;
  $(this).after(det);
  $('#dropdownlist').css('width', $(this).width());
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px #000;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

li {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

#demo {
  postion: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <input id="editabletext" type=text>
</div>
```

You `backtick` instead of single or double quote for getting the entire element.

Hope this will help.